# python - cannot detect if file uploaded in request.files

Tags: python, html

Im using python3 and i want to detect if a file has uploaded , for some reason i get the same result if i upload a file and if i dont upload.

HTML code:

```
  <h3>Add new customer:</h3>
  <form method="post" action="customerAdd" style="display: inline;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="customer">Customer name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="customer" name="customer" required>
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="text" multiple/>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)"/>
  </form>
```

python code:

```
@app.route("/customerAdd", methods=["GET","POST"])
def customer_add():
    data = dict(request.form)
    files = request.files
    c.print_info("FILE", files)
    c.print_info("info", request.files.get('filepath'))
    c.print_info("Len", len(request.files))
```

If i upload a file this what i see in the logs:

```
'FILE', ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'abc.txt' ('text/plain')>), ('file', <FileStorage: 'abc2.txt' ('text/plain')>)]
api_1             | 1647179071 [61], INF, info (None,)
api_1             | 1647179071 [61], INF, Len (1,)
```

And if empty:

```
'FILE', ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
api_1             | 1647179071 [61], INF, info (None,)
api_1             | 1647179071 [61], INF, Len (1,)
```

I have tried to use like all suggest with:

```
len(request.files) != 0:
```

But i get the same reasult, the only difference is the "FILE" log that prints request.files output is without any filename inside.
What am i doing wrong ?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Flask (if not specify your question!) you should be able to use:

```py
# "file" is comes from the name: of your input tag
files = flask.request.files.getlist("file")
for file in files:
    if file.filename !='':
        # Do something with file, file.save() etc.
```

Comment: Documentation and examples can be found from https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/